# Many intent skip in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have three Activity. There skip sequence is A->B->C.

When A skip to B, A cannot be finished. When B skips to C, how to finish the two Activity of A and B?

If B does not skip to C, it can press back to A.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

when you are starting your C Activity,for clearing your backStack from Activity A and B use **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** like :

```
intent = new Intent(context,C.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

you can have more information on : [Task and BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Comment: I try this method. it can not .